# AKS loadbalancer expose different external IP address

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops

Hi i have been deploying and exposing my web api container image using azure-devops to azure kubernetes service (container image ) . i have created multiple applications why each application gets new external IP address ? Is it by default when we use type as load balancer ?

I also tried using node port but in node port case external IP is none.

`deployment deployment-name --type=LoadBalancer --port 80  --name=service-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep, this behaviour is by default, if you want them all have the same external IP you should use the ingress resource:

> Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to
>   services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules
>   defined on the Ingress resource.

Its a bit of a learning, but its quite mandatory if you want to use kubernetes for anything serious.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: so i have to add this in release pipeline ?

Comment: Can you recommend any tutorial to add ingress controller to AKS ? Is it possible to just add ingress.yaml file in project ? I am using azure devops to build and release container image to AKS .

Comment: its more complicated than that, you first need to deploy a ingress controller and then you can add ingress resource to your project, because without ingress controller nothing will act on the ingress resource